# Cron expression for every other day?

Tags: cron, teamcity

I'm setting up a 2 builds in Teamcity, with scheduled triggering using cron expressions.

I want the builds to alternate every other day. I.e., one gets build on one day, then the other one gets built the next day.

**Under no circumstance do I want the same build to run 2 days back to back.**

Is this sort of scheduling even possible using cron expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible to do using only cron, but you can still get this behavior with a bit of a workaround.  Create a simple script or program in whatever language you prefer that keeps track of the last build program to run.  Any time it is run have it run the build that was not run last, then save that one as the new 'last build'.  Then, run this program using cron every day.

You'll need to figure out what works for saving the last build in a persistent way, one the simpler approaches would be to use a file.